# Asignar colores y formas, para distinguir el sexo en una gráfica pairs

Tags: r, color

Tras hacer la función `pairs`...

```
pairs(datos[,-1],col=datos$sexo,)
```

... no puedo asignar por ejemplo el color azul a las hembras con points, y rojos a los machos.

He intentado utilizar `points` pero no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que parece que ocurre, es que `pairs()` no tiene un parámetro `col`, sino que para establecer el color, debieras usar `bg`. Replicando un ejemplo reproducible de la documentación, sería algo así:

```
pairs(iris[1:4], 
      main = "Anderson's Iris Data -- 3 species",
      pch = 21, 
      bg = c("red", "green3", "blue")[unclass(iris$Species)])
```

En tu caso, si `datos$sexo` es un `factor`, puedes hacer `pairs(datos[,-1],bg=c("red", "blue")[unclass(datos$sexo)],)`, si fuera simplemente una cadena `pairs(datos[,-1],bg=c("red", "blue")[(datos$sexo == 'H')+1],)`